# SQL - Accessing databases using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to access a table that is recreated in a new database each quarter.  The table name stays the same but a new database name is created.
What I'm trying to achieve is using a select statement to include a variable that will look at a specific database with a range of Q317 to Q119.  At the moment I have the select code set up but I have to reuse the same code but change the quarter for each database.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this that I'm currently doing?
To make things trickier the Quarter value has to be a string not an integer.

As you can see I'm no expert and I've tried passing variables to the string which works but I can't successfully manage to have it iterate.

```
declare @tablename varchar(50)
set @tablename = '2'
EXEC('SELECT DISTINCT [GAELTACHT] FROM [EDB_Q' + @tablename + '18].[dbo].[POSTAL_ADDRESS]')
```

This is a simplified version of what I'm currently working with but just to demonstrate the databases I'm working with.

```
SELECT 'Q119' AS Quarter,  Count(BUILDING_ID) FROM Towns.CITY_Q119
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Q418' AS Quarter,  Count(BUILDING_ID) FROM Towns.CITY_Q418
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Q318' AS Quarter,  Count(BUILDING_ID) FROM Towns.CITY_Q318 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Q218' AS Quarter,  Count(BUILDING_ID) FROM Towns.CITY_Q218
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Q118' AS Quarter,  Count(BUILDING_ID) FROM Towns.CITY_Q118 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Q417' AS Quarter,  Count(BUILDING_ID) FROM Towns.CITY_Q417
```

Ideally, I would have 1 select statement that somehow iterates (but using string on integers) from between values 218 to 119.  I don't know if what I'm asking for is even possible?

Comment: Ideally you need to change your design; is that something you can do? On a different note, when using dynamic SQL you should never inject raw strings. Always parametrise or properly quote (which is what you need to do here) your values.

Comment: You need to properly form your dynamic sql, use `SysName` instead of `VARCHAR(n)` and use `QUOTENAME()` function too to quote the table name, note that you can't pass object names as a parameter. Also I suggest to use `sp_execsql` instead of `EXEC`

Comment: Also, it seems that your variable which you named `@TableName` isn't a table name, it's a database name, cause your table name is `[POSTAL_ADDRESS]`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Sami.  I'm totally open to rebuilding from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
DECLARE @quarterStart int = 2
DECLARE @quarterEnd int = 1
DECLARE @yearStart int = 18
DECLARE @yearEnd int = 19

DECLARE @year int
DECLARE @quarter int

DECLARE @quarterForDbName nvarchar(4)
DECLARE @sqlStatement nvarchar(max)

SET @year = @yearStart
SET @quarter = @quarterStart
SET @sqlStatement = ''

WHILE @year <= @yearEnd
BEGIN
   WHILE ((@year < @yearEnd AND @quarter <= 4) OR (@year = @yearEnd AND @quarter <= @quarterEnd))
   BEGIN
      SET @quarterForDbName = 'Q' + CAST(@quarter AS nvarchar(1)) + CAST(@year AS nvarchar(2))
      SET @sqlStatement = @sqlStatement + 'SELECT ''' + @quarterForDbName + ''' AS Quarter, Count(BUILDING_ID) FROM Towns.CITY_' + @quarterForDbName + ' UNION ALL '
      SET @quarter = @quarter + 1
   END
   SET @quarter = 1
   SET @year = @year + 1
END

PRINT SUBSTRING(@sqlStatement, 1, LEN(@sqlStatement) - 10)
```

Result:

```
SELECT 'Q218' AS Quarter, Count(BUILDING_ID) FROM Towns.CITY_Q218 UNION ALL SELECT 'Q318' AS Quarter, Count(BUILDING_ID) FROM Towns.CITY_Q318 UNION ALL SELECT 'Q418' AS Quarter, Count(BUILDING_ID) FROM Towns.CITY_Q418 UNION ALL SELECT 'Q119' AS Quarter, Count(BUILDING_ID) FROM Towns.CITY_Q119
```

Instead of the PRINT statement at the end you can use dynamic SQL:

```
EXEC SUBSTRING(@sqlStatement, 1, LEN(@sqlStatement) - 10)
```

Best wishes
Michael

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for this code. I've modified for the real data I'm working with and get the expected result

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a sequence in your db, please check the below link
https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/sequences.php

```
CREATE SEQUENCE quarter_seq
  AS TINYINT
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY -1
  MINVALUE 119
  MAXVALUE 218
  CYCLE
  CACHE 1;
```

Every time you recreate the database increment that value. I guess you have a script that does that so add a line to increment the sequence.

When you do your select statement use something like this:

```
SELECT Current_Value 
FROM SYS.Sequences 
WHERE name='quarter_seq'
```

And cast it as a string.

More info about sequences and how they work can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Msg 11708, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An invalid value was specified for argument 'INCREMENT BY' for the given data type. - Please check your code and test it before posting. There are people here who would downvote your answer...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you drive your SQL statement creation off of `sysdatabases`.

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
select @sql += case when @sql = '' then '' else 'UNION ALL ' end + char(13) 
            + 'SELECT ''' + right(name, 4) + ''' AS Quarter, Count(Building_id) FROM ' + name + '.Towns.City_' + right(name, 4) + char(13)
  from sys.sysdatabases
 where name like 'EDB_Q%'

print @sql
exec(@sql)
```